# Pass a complete dynamic lucene query syntax to the QueryParser

Tags: lucene

I'm just wondering if there is a way to pass a pure dynamic Lucene syntax query including field:value pairs separated with boolean operators to the QueryParser. The query will be determined at runtime (possibly with a customized query builder). Since QueryParser needs a String(default field name) and an analyzer when its been instantiated, I don't know how to use the code.

Any help on that would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused.  It sounds like your asking if you can use QueryParser to do exactly what it was designed to do...

For a bit of explanation, the analyzer finds terms within the text where necessary, `StandardAnalyzer` is an excellent starting point.  The default field is just that, when you don't give a field for a term, it uses the one passed in here.  The case of search terms without a specified field is covered in the [query syntax docs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview).

Here's a fairly typical use of the QueryParser:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, "myText", analyzer);
Query myQuery = parser.parse("My well-formed query");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Exactly, I'm looking for a classic behavior of the QueryParser to parse a query passed to it, without having to identify any field against which the terms should be queried. Suppose that I want the parser to parse this query: "field1:value1 AND field2:value2 OR...", this query can contain any number of field:value pairs. How QueryParser should be instantiated in this case? I want to query against dynamic number of fields. Using MultiFieldQueryParser didn't help because it expects specific fields and have less flexibility in terms of query syntax capabilities.

Comment: Again, that is standard [`org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html) behavior.  The Analyzer you use should be the same as the one you indexed with, but it really won't much change how it handles parsing query syntax.  Is there some particular problem you are having?

Comment: Can I instantiate the parser as: new QueryParser("field1", analyzer); And then pass the query string to the above parser as: "(field2=value1 AND field3=value3) OR field4:(+value4 +value5)" Considering that the query string does not rely on the field1 default value.

Comment: Well, the constructor requires a `Version` since 3.0, and you'll need to use `:` instead of `=`, as per the other queries you've provided here, but otherwise, yes.  If a particular query does not make use of the default field, that won't cause any problems.